# Unexpected space at the begining of file

Tags: php

For my PHP courses I have to create a note pad which start with a sample text, when I edit it and click on the save button, the text inside the file is edited and saved. So if I refresh my page / open the file directly I have the new content edited by the user displayed.

It works, but I have some unexpected space in my file.

If I put at the first character on the first line "sample text", I'll not see "sample text" but instead:

> ```
>       sample text
> ```

And that's only for the first line, what ever if I edited the file manually or with my page. All the next lines start at the first characters.

Below my notes.txt file (where my notes are) after an edit from the web page:

```
Mes jeux préférés:&#13;&#10;    =&#62; Fallout 3&#13;&#10;    =&#62; Natural Selection 2&#13;&#10;    =&#6    2; L4D2
```

I don't see any strange character in at the beginning of the file.

index.php:

```
<?php

define('FICHIER_DE_NOTES', 'notes.txt');
$fichier = fopen(FICHIER_DE_NOTES, 'r+');

if (array_key_exists('note', $_POST)) {

    $note = filter_var($_POST['note'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    ftruncate($fichier, 0);
    fseek($fichier, 0);
    fputs($fichier, $note);
    $updateMessage = 'Vos notes ont été sauvegardés!';

} else {

    $note = '';

    while ($ligne = fgets($fichier)) {
        $note = $note . $ligne;
    }
}

fclose($fichier);

include 'index.phtml';
?>
```

And my index.phtml:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Bloc Note</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Bloc Note</h1>

    <form method="post" action="index.php" >
        <p>Voici votre bloc note. Ajoutez-y du texte et cliquer sur "Sauvegarder".</p>

        <textarea id="textarea" name="note" rows="16" cols="50">
            <?= $note ?>
        </textarea>
        <br/><br/>
        <label>
            <input type="submit" value="Sauvegarder">
        </label>
        <?php if (isset($updateMessage)) {
            echo $updateMessage;
        } ?>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

I use vim and PHP5.

Tell me if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either update your html:

```
<textarea id="textarea" name="note" rows="16" cols="50"><?php echo $note ?></textarea>
```

Or in your php script:

```
if (array_key_exists('note', $_POST)) {
   $_POST['note'] = trim($_POST['note']); //added this line
   $note = filter_var($_POST['note'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
   ftruncate($fichier, 0);
   fseek($fichier, 0);
   fputs($fichier, $note);
   $updateMessage = 'Vos notes ont été sauvegardés!';

} else {

   $note = '';

   while ($ligne = fgets($fichier)) {
      $note = $note . $ligne;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The whitespace comes from your HTML:

```
<textarea id="textarea" name="note" rows="16" cols="50">
    <?= $note ?>
</textarea>
```

You should use the following:

```
<textarea id="textarea" name="note" rows="16" cols="50"><?php echo $note ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because of extra white spaces in the  tag of your HTML file:

```
    <textarea id="textarea" name="note" rows="16" cols="50">
        <?= $note ?>
    </textarea>
```

Try to do like:

```
    <textarea id="textarea" name="note" rows="16" cols="50"><?= $note ?></textarea>
```